# When making multiple ajax requests, is there a "good pattern" for tracking which data the responses line up with?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I build a lot of client-side js apps and have worked mostly with Backbone. Backbone always expects your api to return a copy of the created/changed/deleted model when such ajax actions are completed, allowing it to easily determine which "model" just got updated.

I'm working in a new scenario (new framework, freshly built API) in which all I get back from the API are success/error status codes. The whole "return the entire model" seems like a crutch...but the more I work trying to keep track of these async actions the more it feels like a necessary one.

Is there some kind of convention (outside of the Backbone world, perhaps) for more easily handling this kind of thing?

Edit: I may want to point out I'm using FLUX so the uni-directional flow is preventing me from just cross-wiring everything on either side of the dispatcher.

Comment: One thought: All my api calls are triggered by actions, but wrapped in promises. I could capture those promises and pass them on to the store through the dispatcher, and then the store could attach some data-aware post-op actions. But would that be considered "bad flux"?

Comment: Without more code, your question is difficult to answer. Using a JavaScript closure around the request should be adequate so that you can make the necessary data tracking. I don't see how else you'd accomplish this if your freshly built API doesn't include something else as a tracking token (which you could send with each request).

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess I assumed there might be some method for approaching the topic, rather than a solution that was specific to my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question title is more clear to me than the description, so I'll go with that.

If you are having difficulties in keeping track of multiple ajax requests results, you should use Promises.

For example, with the [Q library](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) you can do something like this:

```
Q.all([AjaxModel1(), AjaxModel2(), AjaxModel3()])
.spread(function(resultModel1, resultModel2, resultModel3) {

});
```

If what you need to know is how to get a model every time you make a change to them, I would need more details about your framework/server/code.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is a solution that's works with the current api responses (just status codes).

Comment: Alright! But what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you don't return anything specific with the status code, I don't think there is a way to know what requests it belonged to.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess didn't realize how vague my question was. However, these comments do help.